# How Nodejs Send P-Touch Template Command to QL-720NW

Tags: node.js, printing, escpos

I just use Nodejs to send p-touch template code to QL-720NW.

i already followed the steps [how to setup p-touch template](http://download.brother.com/welcome/docp000707/cv_ql720_eng_ptemp_100.pdf).

Also, i try to use [tojocky/node-printer](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer) to send commands to printer.

Here is my code,

```
var rawData = new Buffer([
0x1B, 0x69, 0x61, 0x33, // Use p-touch template
0x5E, 0x49, 0x49, // Initialize p-touch template
0x5E, 0x54, 0x53, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31, // Choose template 1
0x5E, 0x46, 0x46 // Start printing
]);

printer.printDirect({
     data: rawData
     , printer:'Brother QL-720NW' // printer name, if missing then will print to default printer
     , type: 'RAW' // type: RAW, TEXT, PDF, JPEG, .. depends on platform
     , success:function(jobID){
        console.log("sent to printer with ID: "+jobID);
   }
   , error:function(err){console.log(err);}
});
```

But, the printer always get fail and flash in red light. 
Just call brother technical support and search technical spec. Cannot find any idea. Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, i found the core issue.

First, tojocky/node-printer can work with sending ESC/P to QL-720NW.

Secondly, the main issue is came from p-touch template. When you design the label layout. Each ui widget assigned Object name is required to inject a value. If you want a static object, you should remove Object name and tick a checkbox which force the widget cannot modify.

Thirdly, send a commands as follow

1. Switch to P-touch template Mode (ESC ia3)
2. Initialize (^||)
3. Choose template (^TS001)
4. Select Object Name (^ONobject\x0h)
5. Directly insert data (^DI\x05h\x0hHello)
6. Start printing (^FF)

you can print it.

Sample Code:
https://github.com/KingWu/NodePrinterExample

Good luck.

Comment: would you mind sharing your sample code? It would help me a lot... thanks in advance